# .htaccess deny access to all except to one file

Tags: .htaccess

How can I deny access to a complete folder and sub-folders, with the exception of one file?
That file is: toon.php and resides in the same folder.

Answer (score 46):

```
Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch "^toon\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

That is probably the most efficient that you can get.

Answer (score 15):

```
Deny From All
<FilesMatch "^toon\.php$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

Worked for me...

Comment: @AD7six Yes there's a difference. This answer `Deny From All` is `Allow From All` is clearer. Explicit is better than implicit. +1 for this answer.

Comment: @Basj that comment should be an edit to the answer :)

Answer (score 14):

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Private Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user


<Files "toon.php">
Allow from all
Satisfy Any

</Files>
```

Works for me. Dont' forget to configure the .htpasswd file.

Comment: I like this answer. Just want to add that you probably need `AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit` in your server config

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use the `<Directory>` and `<Files>` directives. You can look at the documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#files

In short, you want something like this:

```
<Directory /folder/without/access >
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
</Directory>

<Files "filename">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you're looking for a way to have authentication on an entire site/folder except for a single file, you will find that this method is working very well:

```
#allows a single uri through the .htaccess password protection
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/testing_uri$" test_uri

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=test_uri
Satisfy any
```

Example taken from : [this site](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/allow-single-url/)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following rule to htaccess file in root

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule !toon\.php$ - [F]
```

This will deny access to all files and folders except **toon.php** .

Answer (score 0):

There is a related scenario in **WordPress** admin where you may want to **limit** the access to specific IPs, but leave access for some specific files used by plugins:

```
## /wp-admin/.htaccess ##
Deny from all
allow from 88.222.123.88 #Home 
allow from 88.111.211.77 #Office

<Files "admin-ajax.php">
     Allow from All
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress-specific configuration for Private Area using HTTP password:

```
AuthName "Private Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user

<Files "admin-ajax.php">
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```