# .htaccess deny all access to a folder except from one html file

Tags: .htaccess, exception

I have one mp3 folder that I want to protect. I'm using htaccess file match deny all, but I need access from a audio player in one especific HTML page. Is it possible to create an exception (to the deny all tag) to allow access to one especif file/domain?

Thanks

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407543/htaccess-deny-acces-to-all-except-to-one-file)?

Answer (score 1):

See [Access Denial/Approval by Domain](http://www.novia.net/~tomcat/HowTo/domainrestric.html)

```
<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .yourplayerdomain.com
</Limit>
```