# allow access to only one php file with htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have few media files in a folder and a php file on same folder, I want to deny access for any media file accessing directly, but I want to access those media files only via the php file there.

lets say my_folder containing index.php, movie1.mp4, movie2.mp4 etc, I want to deny movie1.mp4 and movie2.mp4 straightly, but I need to allow by index.php

help me with htaccess handling

Comment: How exactly is `index.php` accessing media files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess deny acces to all except to one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407543/htaccess-deny-acces-to-all-except-to-one-file)

Comment: @anubhava: yes index.php is accessing those media files

Comment: Yes that I know but how is it accessing media files? Using `http` or directly using file operations?

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore files using

```
RewriteRule ^/?/file\.mp4$ - [F,L]
```

You can use this as your *.htaccess* . All the request will be redirected to index.php in that directory & also all the request made to mp4 files will be redirected to index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?/file\.mp4$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```