# Deny access to other files than / and /index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have read [.htaccess deny access to all except to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407543/htaccess-deny-access-to-all-except-to-one-file) and its answers. This works:

```
Order Allow, Deny
<FilesMatch "^index\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but only `http://example.com/index.php` is accepted. **The problem is that `http://example.com/` is rejected.**

**Question: What's the cleanest way to allow `/index.php` and `/` only? (both using index.php)?**

I don't think this is optimal:

```
Order Allow, Deny
<FilesMatch "^index\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

because it mixes Allow/Deny/Rewrite rules.

PS: in my real code, I'd like to accept only `/`, `/index.php`, and also `/test.php` too, but no access to other files (such as `/blah.php`, `/foo.log`).

Comment: Don't put anything else into your public webroot to begin with…

Comment: For sure @deceze, but more generally, how to allow `/index.php` and `/` and no other access?

Comment: Perhaps easier to handle the whole thing via mod_rewrite - a RewriteCond to check if what was originally requested was either just `/` or `/index.php`, and then dependent on that a rule that simply uses the `F` flag to answer with 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @CBroe Probably a good idea, could you post it as an answer? (details with flags are always tricky, so an answer would be interesting).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier to handle the whole thing via mod_rewrite - a RewriteCond to check if what was originally requested was either just `/` or `/index.php`, and then dependent on that a rule that simply uses the F flag to answer with 403 Forbidden. And otherwise, your already existing rule to rewrite everything else to the index.php, can do its job afterwards.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|/index\.php)$
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

(Can only test via https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ right now, which can not always match the real behavior 100%, but I think this should probably do the job.)